# Enums serialized with XmlTypeAttribute instead of DataContractAttribute when updating Silverlight service reference in VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wcf, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, visual-studio-2012

I currently have a server-side class library that contains custom enumerations which is in turn used by a WCF service method.

**Using *Visual Studio 2012*, when I update my service reference two of my custom enumerations no longer are generated in the Silverlight client code proxy.** The rest of the server-side classes and enumerations in my project all come over just fine in the service update.

Service reference updates on my project worked just fine using Visual Studio 2010. It was after installing Visual Studio 2012 that this quit working. Even if I re-open the project in VS2010 I'm still unable to get the two problematic enumerations to come over when updating my service reference.

Any idea why these enumerations would quit being generated, after updating a service reference on a Silverlight project, simply by having Visual Studio 2012 installed?

*UPDATE*

I opened up the generated Reference.cs file in my Silverlight project after updating my service reference and I noticed the following difference on one of the enums that did come over successfully:

```
OLD

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="Location", Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyProject.BusinessLogic")]
public enum Location : int {

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
    None = 0,

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
    Section = 4,

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
    Top = 2,

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
    Bottom = 3,
}


NEW

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.18034")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyProject.BusinessLogic")]
public enum Location {

    /// <remarks/>
    None,

    /// <remarks/>
    Section,

    /// <remarks/>
    Top,

    /// <remarks/>
    Bottom,
}
```

Comment: removing service reference and re-adding works fine?

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately removing and re-adding doesn't help, the enums still do not come over

Comment: @KodeKreachor, I'm from .NET Framework compatibility team. We would like to investigate and understand this better. Could you send us project to reproduce the issue on netfx45compat at microsoft dot com?

Comment: @Praburaj I'm sorry, but given the proprietary nature of the project I cannot send you the project. Please take a look at my updates though and hopefully that will help.